# passing parameters to url in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which involves parsing.I want to pass parameters to url in android. How should I proceed?

Comment: try this [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/xml-parsing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please Try This.

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("your url");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("your parameter","parameter value"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("your parameter","parameter value"));

postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
```

nameValuePairs are used to add parameter in url .

Answer (score 0):

here ya go (works great with paging)

```
    public void Execute(final Request request,final ClientCallBackHandler CallBack)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
        //dunno if this is correct...
            if(CurrentConnection.SvUsr.length() > 0)
            {
                httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                        new AuthScope(CurrentConnection.SvUrl, 80, null, "Digest"),
                        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(CurrentConnection.SvUsr, CurrentConnection.SvPw));
            }
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

            if(CurrentConnection != null)
            {




                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(CurrentConnection.SvUrl);
                try {


                    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    String blah =  SerializeRequest(request);
                    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request",blah));

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    if(CallBack != null)
                    {
                        CallBack.SetStatus(ClientCallBackHandler.ENCODING_EXCEPTION);
                    }

                    return;
                }
                try {
                    if(CallBack != null)
                        CallBack.SetStatus(ClientCallBackHandler.HTTP_DID_START);

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
                    if(response != null)
                    {
                        if(CallBack != null)
                        {
                            CallBack.response = DeserializeResponse(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

                            CallBack.SetStatus(ClientCallBackHandler.HTTP_DID_SUCCEED);                                 
                        }

                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(CallBack != null)
                        {
                            CallBack.SetStatus(ClientCallBackHandler.HTTP_DID_ERROR);
                        }

                        return;
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    if(CallBack != null)
                    {
                        CallBack.SetStatus(ClientCallBackHandler.CLIENT_PROTOCOL_EXCEPTION);
                    }

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    if(CallBack != null)
                    {
                        CallBack.SetStatus(ClientCallBackHandler.IO_EXCEPTION);
                    }                       
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }   

        }

    }).start();




}
```

the SerializeRequest() methode converts youre Request into a String youre service can understand ... for example mine is looking like this:

```
    public String SerializeRequest(Request request) {
    Gson gson = gsonb.create();
    String JScript = gson.toJson(request);
    Log.v(request.getClass().getName(),JScript);
    return JScript;
}
```

the DeserializeResponse() methode does pretty much the opposite of this, so in case of gson:

```
    public Response DeserializeResponse(String Jscript)
{
    Response response = null;

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Jscript);

        Gson gson = gsonb.create();
        response = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), Response.class);
               if(response.ClassName.compareTo("ExceptionResponse")==0)
            response = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), ExceptionResponse.class);           
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        response = new ExceptionResponse();
        ((ExceptionResponse) response).Message = Jscript;
    }
    Log.v(response.getClass().getName(),Jscript);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void postData(final String param, final TextView tv) {

        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest postReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                "https://your URL",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        tv.setText(response); // We set the response data in the
                                                // TextView
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response"+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println("Error [" + error + "]");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("your key", "value");
                params.put("any callback methods", "value");
                params.put("any types", "value");
                return params;
            }

        };

        rq.add(postReq);
```